# When was Tcl v8.5 first released for production?

Tags: date, release, tcl, production

I can't seem to locate this on the web anywhere.

What was the date of the first stable release of Tcl v8.5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I located it:

Tcl/Tk 8.5.0 was released December 20, 2007

According to:

http://wiki.tcl.tk/12753

Answer (score 1):

For a relatively complete list of when each version was released see [Tcl/Tk Changes](http://wiki.tcl.tk/405) on the tcler's wiki.